# exiting on FATAL asserts in google test framework

Tags: googletest

Is there any option or method to exit from google test framework completely without executing any further tests when we have identified a FATAL assert which renders any further testing useless ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific mechanism provided by the library to abort execution, but nothing prevents you from using a standard assertion to abort program execution.

```
#include <cassert>

TEST(TestSuite, TestCase)
{
    assert(<fatal condition>);
    // ...
}
```

If the fatal condition is the result of some test setup that you can control, you might be interested in learning about Google Test's support for [Death Tests](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Death_Tests).

Comment: thanks we ended up using assert from c++, probably googletest should include an abort mechanism for clean shutdown

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to use the GTEST_FATAL_FAILURE_ macro. You can use it like this

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(TestSuite, TestCase)
{
    // ...
    
    if (somethingHappens) {
      GTEST_FATAL_FAILURE_("Text to display when the failure happens");
    }    
}
```

When triggered you will see this in the CLI

```
/home/yourname/yourpath/yourfile.cpp:13: Failure
Text to display when the failure happens
```